# Cannot find where is missing external reference used

Tags: excel

When I open my file, I get the message "missing external reference" (my Excel is in french, so the wording may be slightly different). I know I could break the reference, but I would like to know what I am doing exactly.
The source file disappeared (it is a file located in a temp directory).

As you know, Excel can tell the name of the missing files, but gives no information about where it is used (that sounds crazy to me : if it knows a data is missing, it must know where it is missing).

I tried to find where this reference is used :

- Ctrl-F on the ref name in formulas : nothing
- Macro search in the charts data : nothing
- Macro search in the Pivotfield data sources : nothing
- Macro search in the Shapes texts : nothing

Is there another way of looking this reference ?

It is not my file, but a rather old file uses by different people, and a large file with lots of things in it, so it is impossible to finc any person who can remember what might have been done in the past.

EDIT:
We sent back the file to another person involved in it. And he removed the links without any other check. So I hope the file will work OK that way : wait and see. Anyway, we will probably never know what was wrong in it.

I think this subject can be closed. It is still a detailed list of what should be checked in case of a broken link, and for that is useful.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-links-external-references-in-a-workbook-fcbf4576-3aab-4029-ba25-54313a532ff1) Also, maybe is a reference in VBA? did you check the references in VBA editor?

Comment: Thank you for the link. I did not check the "Names" before. And I found some names coming from another file that cannot be found on my computer, but this file is not my first missing file. I removed the names after I have checked they are not used, saved my file. But still get the "missing reference".

Comment: How about Conditional Formatting and Data Validation? (written in [this](https://trumpexcel.com/find-external-links-excel/))

Comment: I checked the Conditional Formatting, and there is no Data Validation. The problem is still here.